# Difference between the group $C_4$ and $Z_4$?

Tags: group-theory, notation

Since they are both cyclic group and both have the same elements, why do we sometimes use $C_4$ and sometimes use $Z_4$?

Comment: $C_4$ is used sometimes to emphasize the cyclic group structure, $\mathbb{Z}_4$ the ring structure. But usually there is no really difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

It's just like how we sometimes use $\frac12$ and some times use $0.5$: it doesn't really matter, but in some situations it feels more right to use one over the other. To me, $C_4$ is about symmetry and $\Bbb Z_4$ is about arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

As generally  $\Bbb Z_4$ is introduced before the concept of isomorphism, $C_4$ and $\Bbb Z_4$  are used for cyclic group of order $4$ and a particular cyclic group of order $4$(which have elements from integers) respectively.
That is $C_4$ is represented for any cyclic group of order $4$ that is we are taking all cyclic groups of order $4$ as abstract conceptually same and it will be considered if we speak generally about cyclic group of order $4$, but $\Bbb Z_4$ as a particular example of $C_4$.

Answer (score 0):

${\mathbb Z_4}$ can also denote the ring of integers modulo 4, so if you just want to talk about the cyclic group then $C_4$ might be preferable.